# C renaming program not renaming

Tags: c, rename

Everything I know about C (not much) tells me this program should be working. But it's not.

When opening in OS X, terminal just says "Abort trap: 6" and ends with no result.

The filename and fullname variables in the rename function are correct when running in Xcode debugger. Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;

    char value1[26], value2[70], idcode[11], filename[16], fullname[64], filenamestring[16], fullnamestring[64];

    // Opening file.

    FILE *nomes;
    nomes = fopen("/Users/EA/Desktop/Songs/backup.txt", "rt");
    if(nomes == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir backup.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Skipping beggining of file until first value.

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            fscanf(nomes, "%*s");
        }

    // Reading first value, and repetition.

    while(fscanf(nomes, "%s", value1) == 1)
    {
        j = k = 0;

        // Extracting idcode from value1.

        for(i=7; i<18; i++)
        {
            idcode[j] = value1[i];
            j++;
        }

        // Filling the complete filename.

        strcat(filename, ".mp4");

        // Reading second value, the "human" filename.

        fscanf(nomes, "\n%[^\n]", value2);
        for(i=6; i<70; i++)
        {
            fullname[k] = value2[i];
            k++;
        }

        // Transforming filenames into strings for rename function.

        strncpy(filenamestring, filename, 16);
        strncpy(fullnamestring, fullname, 64);

        // Renaming the files.

        rename(filename, fullname);

        // Skipping useless data before the next cycle.

        for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            fscanf(nomes, "%*s");
        }
    }

    // Closing file and ending program.

    fclose(nomes);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Well you're not checking the return value of `rename` (and printing `errno` if it fails), so how can we know?

Comment: Could it be a file permissions issue? Check the return value of `rename()`, as suggested.

Comment: you are doing `strcat(filename, ".mp4");` on an uninitialized `filename`.

Comment: `fscanf(nomes, "%*s");` needs a destination string, no?

Comment: If you had compiled with all the warnings enabled the compiler would have told you of some things that should be fixed.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: for readability/understandabillity, only one variable declaration per statement, only one statement per line.

Comment: please consistently indent the code, suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: It compiles without error on my MAC and exit because it doesn't find the file (Erro ao abrir backup.txt). Can you please post the content of the backup.txt file so that I can test it?

Comment: the code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, a real headache to debug and/or maintain.   Suggest using #define's or an enum to give the numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fscanf(nomes, "%s", value1) == 1)`, there is no maximum char limit on the characters that are placed into value1.   This can result in a buffer overflow, which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Note fscanf() will automatically append a NUL char to the input, so the max length modifier needs to be (in this case) 25

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces as that allows many indent levels and is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts

Comment: Please post the contents of the input file, so we can compare it with your code

Comment: the `for()` loop that is filling `idcode[]` fails to set the final byte to '\0' so the result is NOT a valid string

Comment: regarding this line: `strcat(filename, ".mp4");`, the array filename[] has not been initialized to a valid string (including a single byte of '\0', so it is undefined behaviour as to where `strcat()` will chance upon a '\0' in memory.  this can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding this line: `fscanf(nomes, "\n%[^\n]", value2);`  It seems the code is trying to skip a leading white space (I.E. '\n')  however, there is also tabs, spaces to be considered.  Also the format specifier `%[^\n]` can overrun the input buffer.  Suggest: `fscanf(nomes, " %69[^\n]", value2);` (notice the leading space in the format specifier and the limiting of the max number of characters to be read

Comment: the array `idcode[]` is set, but not used.  all references to `idcode[]` could be eliminated and just consume 10 characters from the file and ignore them